# Function displayOpenXAds() is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I've a function called `displayOpenXAds()` at `acciones.js` file defined as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function displayOpenXAds(zone_id) {
        var m3_u = (location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https://openx.elclarinweb.com/www/delivery/ajs.php' : 'http://openx.elclarinweb.com/www/delivery/ajs.php');
        var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999999);
        if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
        document.write("<scr" + "ipt type='text/javascript' src='" + m3_u);
        document.write("?zoneid=" + zone_id);
        document.write('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
        if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
        document.write(document.charset ? '&amp;charset=' + document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset=' + document.characterSet : ''));
        document.write("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
        if (document.referrer) document.write("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
        if (document.context) document.write("&context=" + escape(document.context));
        if (document.mmm_fo) document.write("&amp;mmm_fo=1");
        document.write("'><\/scr" + "ipt>");
    }
}
```

If I try to call the function at every place on the page I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: displayOpenXAds is not defined at line 77

Where line 77 has this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>displayOpenXAds(19)</script>
```

The scripts loads in this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?php echo TEMPLATEURL ?>/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?php echo TEMPLATEURL ?>/js/prefixfree-1.0.6.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?php echo TEMPLATEURL ?>/js/modernizr.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?php echo TEMPLATEURL ?>/js/jquery.tools-1.2.7.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?php echo TEMPLATEURL ?>/js/html5shiv.js"><\/script>')</script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/selectivizr/1.0.3b/selectivizr.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?php echo TEMPLATEURL ?>/js/selectivizr-1.0.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var TEMPLATEURL = '<?php echo TEMPLATEURL; ?>';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo TEMPLATEURL ?>/js/acciones.js"></script>
```

Why the function is *not defined*? What is the right way to load the function when page loads completely in order to avoid wait locks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is order of execution. Here's a short recap:

1. The browser starts reading the document.
2. It loads jQuery and other libraries etc.
3. It marks your code (that defines the function) to be executed once the whole document is ready.
4. Eventually we reach line 77 which is evaluated right away, but fails since the function isn't defined yet.
5. We reach the end of the document, document ready fires, your code is run and the function is now defined.